# Expression mapping with flattening in collection

Tags: c#, expression, automapper

I'm currently playing around with `Automapper.Expressions.ExpressionMapping` and stumbled across an issue. These are the involved classes of my problematic entity:

```cs
public class MyDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MyEntityTag> Tags { get; set; } // <- one-to-many relation
}

public class MyEntityTag
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

As you see, the `Tags` collection from the entity is flattened from an object collection to just a string collection. For object mapping this works fine.

When using expression mapping and using the resulting expression with EntityFramework the following works as well:

```cs
q => q.Where(dto => dto.Tags.Any()) // <- typeof(dto) == MyDto
```

Sadly, the following does not work:

```cs
// Boolean Contains(System.String) can not be called with an instance of type MyEntityTag
q => q.Where(dto => dto.Tags.Contains("test"))

// Binary operator Equal is not defined for MyEntityTag and System.String
q => q.Where(dto => dto.Tags.Any(x => x == "test"))
```

I ofc understand what's going on, but I'm wondering if there is a way to tell AutoMapper how to correctly translate the expressions.

Best regards

Comment: `x => x.Where(y => y.Tags.Any(z => z.Tag == "test"))`

Comment: Sorry, I will edit my post to make it more clear. The source expression is of type `Expression<Func<IQueryable<MyDto>>>` and will be translated to `Expression<Func<IQueryable<MyEntity>>>` by using AutoMapper.